# SELECT ... FOR UPDATE and MAX()

Tags: mysql, select, innodb

Do `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` in this query lock rows in this table?

Table is in InnoDB and query is inside transaction

```
select max(id) from table1 FOR UPDATE
```

I have this code and it seems `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` doesn't lock rows.

Comment: what makes you think it doesn't lock them?

Comment: And what is that result? maybe you interpret it wrong

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1 FOR UPDATE` - does not lock any rows because it does not actually scan any rows. The required information is retrieved from the table index.

This is hinted if you prepend a `DESCRIBE` to the query, displaying:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Select tables optimized away'
```

`SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1) FOR UPDATE` - will lock this **one row** which matches `MAX(id)` because you explicitly retrieve that row.

`SELECT id FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE` - will lock **all rows** and retrieve `MAX(id)` using a combination of `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`.

This is will again be explained by a `DESCRIBE` query.

Comment: Surely for correctness mysql must do locking (when `id` is indexed presumably it needs to hold a lock on just that record)

Comment: MySQL documentation states that "Select tables optimized away" signifies that "there is no need to read any tables during query execution", at least for 5.5, 5.6, 5.7:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` blocks other sessions from doing `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE`

Use instead `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` which

> sets a shared mode lock on the rows
>   read. A shared mode lock enables other
>   sessions to read the rows but not to
>   modify them. The rows read are the
>   latest available, so if they belong to
>   another transaction that has not yet
>   committed, the read blocks until that
>   transaction ends.

See in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).

Answer (score 2):

perhaps this would work ? :

```
select id from table where id IN (select max(id) from table1) FOR UPDATE
```

Answer (score 2):

I've stumbled on this too and tested this case.

```
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `user_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ds_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `producer_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`ds_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
INSERT INTO `test1` VALUES
(3, 4, 2),
(17, 1, 1),
(18, 1, 9);
```

Thread 1:

```
begin;
select max(ds_id) from test1 where user_id=3 for update;
+------------+
| max(ds_id) |
+------------+
|          3 |
+------------+
```

Thread 2:

```
begin;
select max(ds_id) from test1 where user_id=3 for update;
... waiting ...
```

Thread 1:

```
insert into test1 set user_id=3, ds_id=4, producer_id=1;
commit;
```

Thread 2:

```
+------------+
| max(ds_id) |
+------------+
|          3 |
+------------+
```

It appears InnoDB doesn't lock gap when using group function, just locks existing records. Without group function thread 2 returns 2 rows, including brand new one, as expected.

Answer (score -2):

As in Oracle documentation 
This clause is subject to the following restrictions:
You cannot specify this clause with the following other constructs: the DISTINCT operator, CURSOR expression, set operators, group_by_clause, or aggregate functions.