# SELECT FOR UPDATE

Tags: mysql, innodb, select-for-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SELECT … FOR UPDATE and MAX()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593360/select-for-update-and-max)

Which rows in this query lock ?

```
select max(id) from table where id like '9%' for update
```

what occur if another user run this query ?

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593360/select-for-update-and-max) is related question.

Comment: this is my question. read last line of my question

Comment: Yes, I know. I found it from the last line of your question. And I still think you shouldn't make multiple questions that ask the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have no index on id, this will lock all of the records. But I guess you have such index. So this will lock all records that are matching, including some records in between (if you are locking 3 and 5, 4 is also being locked)

> A SELECT ... FOR UPDATE reads the latest available data, setting exclusive locks on each row it reads. Thus, it sets the same locks a searched SQL UPDATE would set on the rows.

**edit**
In the case of SELECT max(id) FROM ... you don't need to read any rows from the table, because this information can be optained from the index. If you want to lock exactly one row, the correct query would be SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = SELECT max(id) FROM table

Comment: so another select max(id) for update return what?

Comment: select max(id) needs to read only the index, not the row, so it's possible that this won't lock anything, and you need to perform select * where id = select max(id)

Comment: it's possible that this won't lock anything?   select max() for update wont lock rows?

Comment: yes, it's possible, and I've explained why. It will read only the index, not the row. How to lock row which ware not selected?

Comment: in your answer you say "If you have no index on id, this will lock all of the records". and in comment say another thing.  i am wrong?

Comment: Yes, if you have no index on id, than MySQL HAVE TO read the records to perform the operation and it will lock all of them.

Comment: @a.v let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1178/discussion-between-darhazer-and-a-v)

Answer (score 2):

I would make an *educated guess* that it depends on the [transaction isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/dynindex-isolevel.html).