# select for update and 3 users

Tags: mysql, select, innodb

I have this code and test with 3 users

```
<?php
mysql_query("BEGIN");
$r=mysql_query("SELECT max(Ticket) from ticket FOR UPDATE");
$row=mysql_fetch_row($r);
$k=$row[0];
echo $k;
for ($j=1;$j<100000;$j++) {
    $k++;
    $r=mysql_query("insert into ticket (Ticket) values ('$k')");
}
mysql_query("COMMIT");
?>
```

I expect to see this result

```
user1 0

user2 9999

user3 19998
```

but i see this result

```
user1 0

user1 **9999**

user3 **9999**
```

it seems user2 and user3 run code at same time even if I have a select for update

Comment: what type of field Ticket? Seems like you have increase its width

Comment: varchar. your comment is an answer. :) . write it as answer

Comment: See this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593864/select-for-update/6594355#6594355

You are performing the locking wrong

Comment: hi Darhazer.problem was another thing. ticket was varchar. it have to be integer to result true value for me.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB uses row-level locking when executing `select ... for update`, i.e. only existing rows are affected.

What you need is MySQL's `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature.