# Lock the maximum value in MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, locking, record-locking

I am using the following query on MySQL using PHP

```
$sql = SELECT MAX(SrNo) FROM cart;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

The structure of table CART is

`CART (SrNo int(10));`

Now I am using the result to do some kind of processing and inserting the maximum value into this table by incrementing one. My problem is that if user1 has got the maximum value of `SrNo` and is in-between the processing. During this time user2 also requests the server got the same maximum value of SrNo as user1 got and starts processing.

Now when both are done with the processing + insertion into the table, I will have two duplicates in the table CART. How can I prevent this from happening?

**In other words, I want no one else to get the maximum value of `SrNo` until unless one user is finished doing its processing.**

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593864/select-for-update/6594355#6594355

Comment: A `SELECT FOR UPDATE` will work if both `SELECT` and `UPDATE` are performed within a single MySQL session. From question I assume it is not the case. I might be wrong though, in which case it would be the solution

Comment: Suppose I put `SELECT...FOR UPDATE`, now how to release the lock after I am done with my processing?

Comment: @Mchl: Select for Update lock the row across ALL connections!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wouldn't you be fine with the AUTO_INCREMENT feature for PRIMARY KEY?

```
create table cart ( SrNo int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

then just simply insert new lines and it will automatically increment the new values. That would probably very easily do the trick you are (maybe?) trying to do.

But if you need to lock the maxmium, you can do this:

```
start transaction;
select max(SrNo) from cart for update;
/* do some other stuff, insert the max value + 1 etc... */
commit;
```

Remember: **You should use transaction for any operation which is not 1 single query!**

Comment: Hi Tomas. Thank you for the answer. Can you please clarify that by mentioning `commit` will end the `transaction`? In other words, no one would be able to find out the maximum `SrNo` during the transaction....Am I right?

Comment: Or, at least no one performing transaction like this one, with that `select .. for update`. I'm not sure about normal select. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

NOt a trivial thing with a web application that creates a new connection on each request.
You'd need to add a `lockedBy` and `lockedTime` columns to this table, and put into them an `ID` of user that requested the lock as well as timestamp of when the lock was requested. You need the timestamp, so that you can ignore locks that are longer than certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

if you set SrNo as the primary key on the table, then the secound time you try to add the row going to fail, and if it fails, you can request a new number.

```
ALTER TABLE cart ADD PRIMARY KEY (SrNo);
```

Comment: is there a reason for you to not use mysqls auto increment functionalaty? like CREATE TABLE cart (SrNo SERIAL);

Comment: I can't user auto increment, the design is like that. Along with SrNo there are other columns, I mentioned only SrNo in my question because of simplicity.

Comment: ok, but using primary key or a unique key, protects you from dubplicates, then you just need to add some php to handle the failed insert