# increment unique with its table wide maximum + 1

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have table like the following:

```
Base = declarative_base()
class MyTable(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    update_id = Column(Integer, unique=True)
```

An instance of that Table is created somewhere during the program. Later, at a certain point after the creation (that is why I can't use the primary key), I would like to set the `upload_id` to its table wide maximum + 1. The idea is to use the update_id to compare which object was updated first.

**My problem:** How can I secure this against race conditions? 
For instance, while instance A get's the maximum to increment it another instance B get's the same and both would end up with the same value (apart from the fact that value has to be unique)?

I tried the following method in MyTable:

```
def set_update_id(self):
    q = database.session.query(func.max(MyTable.upload_id) + 1) 
    new_id = q.with_for_update().scalar()                   
    if new_id is None:
        new_id = 1
    self.upload_id = new_id                                  
    database.session.commit()
```

When holding (`set_trace`) the code before the commit and trying to call the method for a different instance, I get `Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction` for the second call, after the first call's `commit` was executed.

*Note*: I found solutions to increment securely a value by one, but my point is (and that's why I think this isn't a duplicated question): How do I increment by the maximum value + 1 of the column?

Comment: you should have a `Base = decalrative_base()` and be inheriting from that instead (It wont solve your problem ... but )

Comment: Why not just use a `datetime` (or `timestamp`) column for this purpose? You can have column `updated_at`, which will be updated independently of any other rows in that table. Later you can use it for comparisons of order.

Comment: @van there could still be a case where datetime is equal for two rows and I would like to avoid those cases

Comment: Fair enough. Still I think i would use some other column (like the `id`) for ranking these to have unique ordering instead of having to deal with locking on write.

Comment: @van that is exactly what I would like to do. The point is, the ID can't be set at initialization time. Then, how do I get an auto-incrementing ID somewhen after the initialization of the instance?

Comment: I meant that you can use both `(timestamp, id)` later when you need to figure out the order of updates, *not* during the update phase itself.

Comment: @van sure, but since is set in multiple processes, `timestamp` might not yet be set for the "real first" when the seconds checks for it yielding both to be identified as first at a certain point

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to lock the entire table on inserts. Any other method will fall prey to race conditions or uniqueness violations. You are better off implementing this as a trigger in raw sql than trying to get it to work in sql alchemy.

Note: Your method may not work if you have an index on that column as not all the rows have to be read to identify the max value. Resulting in only 1 row being locked. See [SELECT FOR UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593864/select-for-update)