# deadlock when selecting max() for update on auto increment primary key

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-deadlocks

I have a table defined in this way:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `measure` (
  `measureId` bigint NOT NULL,
  `sensorId` int NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` bigint NOT NULL,
  `data` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

ALTER TABLE `measure`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`measureId`),
  ADD KEY `measure_index` (`sensorId`,`timestamp`);

ALTER TABLE `measure`
  MODIFY `measureId` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

*measureId* is mostly used as auto increment, but sometimes I need to specify *measureId* during insert. I use the following transaction for my application:

```sql
begin;
select max(measureId) from measure for update;
-- use the max id retrieved to create measurements
insert into measure values (max_id + 1, ...), (max_id + 2, ...), ...;
-- do other stuff
commit;
```

I use *select ... for update* to avoid insertions between selecting *max(measureId)* and and adding the new rows. Without using it, the transaction would fail since the id would be already taken via autoincrement (I use the default isolation REPEATABLE READS).

In a non concurrent environment the transaction succeeds, but I get a deadlock when this happens between two transactions:

```sql
T1: select max(measureId) ...;
T2: select max(measureId) ...; -- starts waiting
T1: into measure values (max_id + 1, ...), ...;
-- ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Why should this be a dealock? T1 should already have the lock on the primary key index ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593864/select-for-update)).

How can i fix this?

Edit: Added output of the innodb status monitor, not sure what is happening. I seems to me that transaction 2 (below) is waiting for a lock it already has.

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2023-01-23 13:58:10 139850373236480
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 41530, ACTIVE 62 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1251, OS thread handle 139850310264576, query id 5030779 172.19.0.1 root optimizing
select max(measureId) from measure for update

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 177 page no 22722 n bits 360 index PRIMARY of table `WEATHER_STATION`.`measure` trx id 41530 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 177 page no 22722 n bits 360 index PRIMARY of table `WEATHER_STATION`.`measure` trx id 41530 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 290 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 80000000004aa795; asc      J  ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000000a1f8; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 82000000a913e6; asc        ;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000192; asc     ;;
 4: len 8; hex 8000000063cac0ed; asc     c   ;;
 5: len 4; hex 6666ea41; asc ff A;;


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 41529, ACTIVE 163 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1250, OS thread handle 139850312378112, query id 5030780 172.19.0.1 root update
insert into measure values (4892566, 1, 2, 3)

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 177 page no 22722 n bits 360 index PRIMARY of table `WEATHER_STATION`.`measure` trx id 41529 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

Record lock, heap no 290 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 80000000004aa795; asc      J  ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000000a1f8; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 82000000a913e6; asc        ;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000192; asc     ;;
 4: len 8; hex 8000000063cac0ed; asc     c   ;;
 5: len 4; hex 6666ea41; asc ff A;;


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 177 page no 22722 n bits 360 index PRIMARY of table `WEATHER_STATION`.`measure` trx id 41529 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

Comment: Check the deadlock section of innodb status monitor output. It will tell you what statements hold what locks and what exactly caused the deadlock.

Comment: @Shadow I added the output to the question. Still not sure what is happening. Sorry I don't have a lot of experience on databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, get rid of `measureid`:

```
CREATE TABLE `measure` (
  `sensorId` int NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` bigint NOT NULL,
  `data` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(sensorId, timestamp)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Consider using the `TIMESTAMP(n)` datatype, where `n` is the number of decimal places (fraction of a second).  The max is 6 (microseconds).  This will give you a variety of date/time functions that will probably be clearer than futzing with a `BIGINT`.

Suggest shrinking `sensorId` to a smaller datatype.  For example, `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` would allow 65K sensors in a 2-byte column.

With those changes, the table (data+indexes) will take about half the disk space.  This will have a favorable impact on speed.

With that, you won't need the `SELECT` (another speedup).  And you can possibly do nothing more than the multi-row `INSERT`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'll probably change my design. Isn't it better to use DATETIME(n) to avoid the y2038 problem? It should be only 1 byte difference in size. I'm still curious about the reason for the deadlock

Comment: @ptrchv - 2am-3am is a problem once a year with `DATETIME`.  y2038 -- Well that's 15 years off.  Think about the computer you had 15 years ago.  Is it still alive and being used?  You should _plan_ to replace all the hardware and software every 5 years or so, else it becomes impossible to upgrade.

Comment: And,,, Fractional seconds may be overkill.  For meteorological measurements, once a second is probably overkill.

Comment: And... A guess about the deadlock -- Your code is doing abnormal stuff with the auto_increment column.  Perhaps you are locks that are not normally a nuisance but show up by hanging onto `MAX(id)` for the duration of the transaction.  (My answer, instead, avoided such.)